# Clojure equivalent of Scala's andThen

Tags: clojure

Clojure and Scala both have composing functions/methods (`comp` and `.compose` respectively). Scala has a method `.andThen` which works the same way as `.compose`, except it nests the function application in the opposite order. Does an analog of this function exist in Clojure?

I could write it easily enough myself for example like this:
`(defn and-then [& fns] (apply comp (reverse fns)))`, however it seems basic enough that it must already exist, especially since in Clojure it has natural application in converting threading-macro expressions into point-free functions, e.g. the following two expressions would be equivalent in the unary case: `#(->> % a b c)` and `(and-then a b c)`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything built-in, likely because clojure does not have an infix syntax (i.e. `(and-then f g)` is not as clear as `f andThen g`). As you already recognized `->` and `->>` are what's generally used in it's place.

Comment: I agree `and-then` isn't the best name for a prefix language, but I was hoping Clojure had something with a name that made more sense. The threading macros are great in a lot of situations, but there are other times when having a function (not a macro) that returns a function (not the computed value) is beneficial.

Comment: Indeed. It looks like a number of projects just define their own `rcomp` with the definition you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such built-in functionality in Clojure. The code example you provided is good enough I believe.